# jQuery UI + SlickGrid error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slickgrid

I add to my page SlickGrid from http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

I use:
- jquery-1.8.2.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js
- jquery.event.drag-2.0.min.js

And I have an error:

```
Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'
```

So I changed jQuery UI to 1.8.16 and now I don't have this error, but I have error:

```
Accordion is not a function
```

When I use Accordion. When use Autocomplete() or Dialog() I have this error too.

So I must use jQuery UI 1.9.1, but How I can use Slick Grid?

> **Edit:** (fiddles based off of original by ryan niemeyer)
>
> example using 1.8.13 (works)  http://jsfiddle.net/A9NrP/404/
>
> example using 1.9.1 (fails)  http://jsfiddle.net/A9NrP/405/

Comment: For what it's worth, the widget methods are lower-case. It's `accordion()` or `dialog()`, not `Accordion()` or `Dialog()`.

Comment: Ok i use accordion and dialog. Error is when I use jQuery UI 1.9.16. I have firsty error from my posts

Comment: can you recreate the error in jsbin or in jsfiddle? you could get better answers if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the pull request here, it should fix your problem: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/462